# Magento 2 - cant modify quote before placing order

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, sales-order, quote

I try to delete all items with a custom product type from the quote *before* the order is placed. So I created an observer for the event `sales_order_place_before`. In this observer I am collection all items with my custom product type `ral_surcharge` and try to delete them from the quote. But after the order is placed, the items are still there.

What am I doing wrong?

**MODULE/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_before">
        <observer instance="Company\RalSurcharge\Observer\Webapi\Sales\OrderPlaceBefore"
                  name="company_ralsurcharge_observer_webapi_sales_orderplacebefore_sales_order_place_before"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**MODULE/etc/webapi_soap/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_before">
        <observer instance="Company\RalSurcharge\Observer\Webapi\Sales\OrderPlaceBefore"
                  name="company_ralsurcharge_observer_webapi_sales_orderplacebefore_sales_order_place_before"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**MODULE/Observer/Webapi/Sales/OrderPlaceBefore.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\RalSurcharge\Observer\Webapi\Sales;

use \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Company\RalSurcharge\Helper\RalSurcharge as RalHelper;

class OrderPlaceBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    private $quoteFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Company\RalSurcharge\Helper\RalSurcharge
     */
    private $ralHelper;

    public function __construct(
        RalHelper $ralHelper,
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    ) {
        $this->ralHelper = $ralHelper;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $quoteId = $observer->getOrder()
                            ->getQuoteId();
        $quoteModel = $this->quoteFactory->create();
        $quote = $quoteModel->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
        $this->ralHelper->main($quote);
    }



}
```

**MODULE/Helper/RalSurcharge.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\RalSurcharge\Helper;

class RalSurcharge
{
    private $allItems;
    private $quote;

    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     */
    public function main($quote)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/zend_debug.log');
        $this->logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $this->logger->addWriter($writer);

        $this->logger->info("Hello from main");

        $this->quote = $quote;
        $allItems = $this->quote->getAllItems();
        $collection = $this->getItemsWithProductType("ral_surcharge");
        $this->deleteItemsFromQuote($collection)
    }

    private function deleteItemsFromQuote($items)
    {
        if (empty($items)) { return false; }

        foreach($items as $item) {
            $this->logger->info("delete item '". $item->getName() . "' from quote.");
            $this->quote->deleteItem($item);
        }
        $this->quote->save();
    }

    private function getItemsWithProductType($type)
    {
        if (empty($this->allItems)) { return false; }

        $collection = [];
        foreach($this->allItems as $item) {
            if ($item->getProductType() === $type) {
                $collection[] = $item;
            }
        }
        return $collection;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sales_order_place_before`  is not the right event to Modify quote items before order placement.

`sales_order_place_before` event fire after quote converted to order that why it is not the right place.

I think you can use `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement::submit` because of this function hit before quote convert to order.

Comment: Now I understand why it failed, thank you! I replaced the event with `checkout_submit_before` now it works.